# Objeto aparece ao iniciar (pressionar) o evento OnLongClickListener e desaparece ao terminar o mesmo (soltar)

Tags: android

Estou pensando em uma forma de fazer com que uma view com o atributo `visibility: gone` ficar visível ao pressionar com clique longo na tela e sumir assim que soltar, parecido com e o feito do Instagram. Alguém tem ideia de como fazer?

[image: App Instagram]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta forma, utilizando o evento `setOnTouchListener`, dentro deste evento, você irá se deparar com o método `onTouch` que irá resgatar a ação que o usuário está utilizando, a `ACTION_DOWN`, para quando o usuário está segurando o botão e `ACTION_UP`, para quando o usuário soltar o botão:

```
my_btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Abra sua View

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               // Feche sua View

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```